# QuickSight - Filter ID's based on two category filter combinations

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have data like below table . So Here a person belongs multiple categories in Category Type A and Category Type B .

[image]

I will have to filters like Category A with values ( AA, B,C,BB) and CAtegory B Filter with values ( ab,ac,bb,cc,as)

now I if I select Category A filter with value as AA then I need only person qualify with that filter - so result is Person - 3 & 4

IF I select B in Category A then result is NULL because those qualify person have other category type in Category A

Same way for category B filter ...

now If I select Category A = AA and Category B = bb then result will be Person 3